# POST/ 405 method not found - Slack error while integrating chatbot

Tags: python, post, slack-api, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am getting some kind of 405 method not found error, while integrating my rasa chatbot with slack. ? please put some light on the issue.

`\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\policies\keras_policy.py:265: FutureWarning: 'KerasPolicy' is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0. Use 'TEDPolicy' instead.
  current_epoch=meta["epochs"],
2020-04-27 02:59:51 INFO     rasa.core.policies.ensemble  - MappingPolicy not included in policy ensemble. Default intents 'restart and back will not trigger actions 'action_restart' and 'action_back'.
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://e8045282.ngrok.io/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\sanic\app.py", line 940, in handle_request
    handler, args, kwargs, uri, name = self.router.get(request)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\sanic\router.py", line 411, in get
    return self._get(request.path, request.method, "")
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\sanic\router.py", line 452, in _get
    raise method_not_supported
sanic.exceptions.MethodNotSupported: Method POST not allowed for URL /
2020-04-27 03:13:47 WARNING  rasa.core.channels.slack  - Received retry #1 request from slack due to http_timeout.
2020-04-27 03:13:49 ERROR    rasa.core.channels.slack  - Exception when trying to handle message.The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'internal_error'}
2020-04-27 03:13:49 ERROR    rasa.core.channels.slack  - The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'internal_error'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\slack.py", line 312, in process_message
    await on_new_message(user_msg)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\channel.py", line 83, in handler
    await app.agent.handle_message(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\agent.py", line 486, in handle_message
    return await processor.handle_message(message)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\processor.py", line 107, in handle_message
    await self._predict_and_execute_next_action(message.output_channel, tracker)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\processor.py", line 538, in _predict_and_execute_next_action
    action, tracker, output_channel, self.nlg, policy, confidence
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\processor.py", line 651, in _run_action
    await self._send_bot_messages(events, tracker, output_channel)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\processor.py", line 580, in _send_bot_messages
    await output_channel.send_response(tracker.sender_id, e.message())
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\channel.py", line 186, in send_response
    await self.send_text_message(recipient_id, message.pop("text"), **message)
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\slack.py", line 39, in send_text_message
    channel=recipient, as_user=True, text=message_part, type="mrkdwn",
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\slack\web\base_client.py", line 226, in _send
    return SlackResponse(**{**data, **res}).validate()
  File "c:\users\shubham\anaconda3\envs\resturantchatbot\lib\site-packages\slack\web\slack_response.py", line 176, in validate
    raise e.SlackApiError(message=msg, response=self)
slack.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'internal_error'}`

this the error i got when running th ngrok integration with slack. 
Slack Error :

`HTTP Requests                                                                                                           -------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   POST /webhooks/slack/webhook   201 Created                                                                              POST /webhooks/slack/webhook   200 OK                                                                                   POST /webhooks/slack/webhook   200 OK                                                                                   POST /                         405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please look at the guide in  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a question. There is no code here for anyone to assist with.

Comment: Also, look at the final error in your traceback. Looks like you're trying to use an unsupported operation for the API endpoint. For example, using a POST when the endpoint only supports a GET.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue. It is saying Post is not allowed on '/' (home). Not sure why slack is posting event request on '/' (home) it should on '/webhooks/slack/webhook' so when I used postman to post webhook URL with sample message (https://api.slack.com/events/message) it went fine.

[image]

Did the issue got sorted for you.

Thank you,
Vivek